# android studio php post data

Tags: php, android

I have a project in android studio and i have some problem 
I don;t know how to fix it 
I wish someone help me to solve problem

**PHP**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mosabalzouby", "12Qwaszx", "mosabalzouby");


$SCIENTIFIC_NAME = $_POST["SCIENTIFIC_NAME"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM medicine WHERE SCIENTIFIC NAME = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $SCIENTIFIC_NAME);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$MEDICINE_NO, $ALTERNATIVE, $SIDE_EFFECT, $SCIENTIFIC_NAME,$TRADE_NAME,$describe_med);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["ALTERNATIVE"] = $ALTERNATIVE;
    $response["describe med"] = $describe_med;
    $response["TRADE NAME"] = $TRADE_NAME;
    $response["SIDE EFFECT"] = $SIDE_EFFECT;
    $response["SCIENTIFIC NAME"] = $SCIENTIFIC_NAME;

}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and the android class :

```
public class MedicineRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://mosabalzouby.aba.ae/search.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public MedicineRequest(String SCIENTIFIC_NAME, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("SCIENTIFIC_NAME", SCIENTIFIC_NAME);

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

**RESPONSE** from api service

> {"success":false}

I don't know where the error
I think all thing is right

please help me

Comment: generate complete php post url in log and try the same using POSTMAN. Is SCIENTIFIC_NAME send has available data in database? may be a spelling mistake?

Comment: are you sure SCIENTIFIC NAME  field   has space !!!!

Comment: i fix the column name but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

In your query, there is a space in your SQL column name `SCIENTIFIC NAME`. I'll bet you ten bucks that's the problem. :)

Comment: i fix the column name but still same problem